# JQuery source code DomEval understanding

Tags: jquery

I'm studying the actual JQuery file for 3.1.1 as a tool to learn Javascript.

In the DOMEval function, there is a line

```
doc.head.appendChild( script ).parentNode.removeChild( script );
```

Am I missing something or is this adding then removing a script element in the head tag?

If so what is the purpose of this line?

Comment: My quick guess is that once the script element is appended, its content gets evaluated by the browser (so removing the element doesn't *un-evaluate* it).

Comment: @Felix Fong - 'm not asking how, I'm asking about the actual source code to JQuery and why that line is implemented.

Comment: `doc` is meaning `document`,and the `head` is self explain,and `appendChile` is mean append a new element and it take one arguments,and about the `removeChild`,why before it need to add `parentNode`,cause it mean then the `removeChild` arguments can take something like a `querySelector` arguments